# Plesk Hosting Magento 2 commands not working

Tags: magento2, command-line, ssh

I'm Using Plesk Hosting Magento 2 installed but i can't use commands any kind of command not working.

i'have tried many different commands all gives error
some can advice will be highly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: can please run pwd command? and show me the output

Comment: yes please check https://snag.gy/nvMCZ5.jpg

Comment: can you please create a info.php file on magento_root_directory with print_r($_SERVER); the find out the path "DOCUMENT_ROOT" path in the output?

Comment: https://muzikhausberlin.de/info.php done

Comment: /var/www/vhosts/muzikhausberlin.de/uploads

Comment: run in terminal : whereis php then send me the output

Comment: bash-4.4$ whereis php
bash: whereis: command not found
bash-4.4$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93997/discussion-between-saphal-jha-and-aadii-mughal).